# Is it possible to swap the location? In MUI DataGrid Slots

Tags: mui-x-data-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AhHb.png)

Is it possible to switch the location? (red box remarked) 
I want to change "quick filter" and "function buttons (filter and export)"

```
<Box sx={{ height: 760, width: '100%', display:'flex',
                    "& .MuiDataGrid-root": { fontWeight: 700 },
                    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": { fontWeight: 700 }}}>
                    <DataGrid
                        rows={ rowData }
                        columns={ columnData }
                        initialState={{
                            pagination: {
                            paginationModel: {
                                pageSize: 12, page: 0
                        }}}}
                        density='compact'
                        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
                        checkboxSelection
                        disableRowSelectionOnClick
                        // processRowUpdate={ processRowUpdate }
                        style={{fontSize:'12px'}}
                        slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
                        disableColumnSelector
                        disableDensitySelector
                        slotProps={{
                            toolbar: {
                              showQuickFilter: true,
                              quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
                            },
                        }}
                    />
                </Box>
```

I tried to find the properties on MUI GridData, could not find any styling for them.